# SQL request to LINQ To SQL with aggregate function

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, sql-to-linq-conversion

I wrote the following basic SQL request, which returns the desired results :

```
SELECT c.IdC, MAX(v.[Date])
FROM TableV v
JOIN TableC c ON v.IdClassified = c.IdC
WHERE v.IdUser = 'MyIdUser'
GROUP BY c.IdC
ORDER BY MAX(v.[Date]) DESC, c.IdC
```

I'd like to "convert" it to LINQ, but I'm having hard times to deal with the aggregate function and the `group by` clause.

Any idea how to convert it to LINQ ?

Comment: How can we do this if you don't tell us the name or the structure of your variables in C#?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary... I tried somehting like `var x = from v in dbContext.TableV join...` and I asked this question to get some help to complete this linq request. Once I'll have it, I'll do my business logic by myself

Comment: So if you look around at answered questions you can see that it typically takes 3-10 mins (often less) to get an answer to any programming question on this site when a question is well worded.  Feel free to think whatever you want, but I've been on this site for many years, and you *might* want to consider my suggestion possibly helpful.   That is, if you want an answer to your question.  If you don't want an answer, then I'd say you are on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find an answer :

```
var qViews = from v in dbContext.TableV
             join c in dbContext.TableC ON v.IdC equals c.IdC
             where v.IdUser == idUser
             group v by v.IdC into grp
             let tri = grp.Max(x => x.Date)
             orderby tri descending
             select new { x = grp.Key /*whatever else*/ };
```

Hope it helps